# Make chart using chart.js using database data

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

So, i think that the title explain what i want to do. I have a database composed of | tempLog | pot | sen | and i want to make a graph using data stored in tempLog and pot. So i made a sketch and as i expected it didn't work, my question is how can i put a single column in a query and then use it in my chart? Should i use an array? Then how i can use it in my chart? Take in mind that i'm using PHP 5.6.30 and for now i will not upgrade it to 7. Thanks for the help :)

Here my sketch if you want to see how a bad programmer i am. (Also a bad english speaker)

```
    <?php
        import("connect.php");
        $link=Connection();//get connection to the db 
    //here i create my arrays
        $record=mysql_query("SELECT `tempLog` FROM `Tabella1` ORDER BY `tempLog`",$link);
        $datax = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
        $datax[0] = $row;
    }
    $record=mysql_query("SELECT `potenza` FROM `Tabella1` ORDER BY `tempLog`",$link);
    $datay = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
        $datay[0] = $row;
    }
    ?>


<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="grafico-linea"></canvas>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grafico-linea').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: <?=json_encode(array_values($datax));?>,//put there the arrays
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Potenza',
                data: <?=json_encode(array_values($datay));?>,//end there
                backgroundColor: "rgba(41,128,185,0.8)"
            }]
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Your `datax` array is a string array (and the lenght of `datax` and `datay` are equal, right?).

Comment: No errors, i'm running it on a virtual machine using Apache2. The problem is that i don't know where i'm doing bad. I'm using arrays bad to store data or i'm using arrays bad in the graph.

Comment: Maybe i should use this to create my arrays:    $data = array();    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($record)) {    array_push($data, $row['tempLog']);    }